# Why does Amazon SWF Workflow not cancel immediately after calling TryCatch.cancel()?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-swf, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am using the below code sample where I am calling the `cancelWF` method to cancel the execution of workflow. The `onCatch` method is successfully invoked with the `RuntimeException("Simply cancel")`, but on the Amazon SWF console the WF does not end immediately, it waits will timeout and ends with a `WorkflowExecutionTerminated` event.

The whole project is available [here](https://github.com/vikkyhacks/ProjectX/tree/master/AWS/SWF/F_ParallelExecution/src/main/java/aws/swf) if you want more info.

```
package aws.swf;

import aws.swf.common.Constants;
import aws.swf.common.DelayRequest;
import aws.swf.common.MyActivityClient;
import aws.swf.common.MyActivityClientImpl;
import aws.swf.common.MyWorkflow;
import aws.swf.common.SWFClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflow;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.WorkflowWorker;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.annotations.Asynchronous;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.Promise;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.core.TryCatch;

import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;

public class D_CancelWorkflow implements MyWorkflow {

    private TryCatch tryCatch;
    private final MyActivityClient activityClient = new MyActivityClientImpl();

    @Override
    public void sum() {
        tryCatch = new TryCatch() {
            @Override
            protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
                System.out.printf("[WF %s] Started exec\n", D_CancelWorkflow.this);
                Promise<Integer> result = activityClient.getNumWithDelay(new DelayRequest("req1", 1));
                cancelWF(result);
                newDelayRequest(result);
            }

            @Override
            protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
                if (e instanceof CancellationException) {
                    System.out.printf("[WF %s] Cancelled With message [%s]\n",
                            D_CancelWorkflow.this, e.getCause().getMessage());
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rethrow(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Asynchronous
    private void newDelayRequest(Promise<Integer> num) {
        activityClient.getNumWithDelay(new DelayRequest("req2", 1));
    }

    @Asynchronous
    private void cancelWF(Promise<Integer> ignore) {
        System.out.printf("[WF %s] Cancelling WF\n", D_CancelWorkflow.this);
        this.tryCatch.cancel(new RuntimeException("Simply cancel"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AmazonSimpleWorkflow awsSwfClient = new SWFClient().getClient();
        WorkflowWorker workflowWorker =
                new WorkflowWorker(awsSwfClient, Constants.DOMAIN, Constants.TASK_LIST);
        workflowWorker.addWorkflowImplementationType(D_CancelWorkflow.class);
        workflowWorker.start();
    }
}
```

This is the event history for one of my execution,

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you *should* do, but I think you're canceling the `tryCatch`, not the workflow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/errorhandling.html#test.cancellation.resources

Comment: Interesting. What happens when you rethrow other type of exception from doCatch? For example RuntimeException that wraps the cancellation one?

Comment: @MaximFateev: Nothing happens, I tried 'reThrow(err)' and 'throw err' but still the workflow does not cancel.

Comment: @Kobi Isn't that how I am supposed to explicitly cancel a TryCatch ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/errorhandling.html#errorhandling.canceltask